# Permission for create aws VPC using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, policy

I want to give minimum permission to my terraform user. I am just creating the VPC only.

**vpc.tf**

```
# Create VPC

resource "aws_vpc" "prj_vpc" {
  provider   = aws.prj-region
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/20"
  tags = {
    Name = "prj-vpc-10.0.0.0/20"
  }
}

# Get all availability zones
data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {
  provider = aws.prj-region
  state    = "available"
}

# Create private subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "prj_private_subnet" {
  provider          = aws.prj-region
  availability_zone = element(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names, 0)
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.prj_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.3.0/24"
  tags = {
    Name = "prj-private-subnet-10.0.3.0/24"
  }
}
```

Policy associated with this user has below json.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteSubnet",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:CreateVpc",
                "ec2:DeleteVpc",
                "ec2:CreateSubnet",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/prj_terraform_file"
        }
    ]
}
```

but when I run the `terraform apply` it gives error for create VPC.

```
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_vpc.prj_vpc: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating EC2 VPC: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: YZow_Zb22lBD6X5fwqYdXXXXXXXXXXXXXfsQyznUuqTNoyDksW_J9W-eY4ngA5xwiRCoMdY97SlCPaPs7LRHXnF7sSf8pmCZWk0ofsLUnawviO3ICw4eLLpNWFSQYbGRYK3w1H8qzuxfc2rdn_LAkOeZ3qILmz2aNEF8Nh
│   status code: 403, request id: 58b59076-a802-4761-886f-9435f29375be
│ 
│   with aws_vpc.prj_vpc,
│   on vpc.tf line 3, in resource "aws_vpc" "prj_vpc":
│    3: resource "aws_vpc" "prj_vpc" {
│ 
╵
```

What else permission I have to add to create VPC ?

Comment: Your code is not related to your error. The error is about `prj_vpc` and your code shows `santo_vpc`. Thus, probably your IAM policy also in the question is incorrect and not the one that you are using.

Comment: that was changed, please have a look again

Comment: Did you Decode the error message as explained in https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/aws-backup-encoded-authorization-failure?

Comment: trying now that

Comment: This is not a terraform question. Not intending to be rude at all, but clarifying terraform only calls the AWS API's and returns its error messages. So it would be the same error if you used the CLI or boto.